# Webix Layout with URL Change and Two Column

Tags: javascript, html, css, webix

If you are a webix guru and used their material skin http://webix.com/demos/material/admin-app/#!/app/forms , you will be well familiar with two column layout.

I want to create a very basic layout which has left side a tree of links and it opens the contents in right side ( like in above theme). Furthermore, I need to change the URL on each click by using history API.

Anybody can provide me a basic layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight code solution will look like next

```
webix.ui({
  cols:[
    { view:"tree", data:tree_data, width:320 },
    { template:"right" }
  ]
});
```

http://webix.com/snippet/6a452f1c

If you want to build a full app, check Webix Jet, it is a micro framework on top of Webix UI that allows to organize the navigation in the neat way.

http://webix.gitbooks.io/webix-jet/content/chapter1.html

Comment: Code is not relevant but this book is.